# How to add more items to the matplotlib legend?

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

When I encountered this problem a couple hours ago I thought it'd only take a few minutes of googling to resolve, but here I am.

I plot all my values using a single plt.bar() call:

```
plt.bar(range(len(vals)), vals, width=1, color=colors)
```

This creates a bar graph where the bars are color coded. When I try to create a legend, it only displays one color along with one label. So for example doing this:

```
labels = ['Group 1', 'Group 2', 'Group 3']
plt.legend(labels,
   loc='best',
   ncol=3)
```

Only shows 'Group 1' on the legend along with one of the many bar colors. How can I add more items to the legend?

I know that this issue is because I am assigning multiple colors in a single plot, but that is the cleanest solution for that part in this case.

Resources I found suggested using "ax.get_legend_handles_labels()", but that returns two empty lists for me.

EDIT:

@falsetru,
Here is a code sample which describes the issue after applying your solution. I included all the relevant parts.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import numpy as np

items= ['item1','item2','item3']           #item names
vals = [1, 2, 3]                           #values to be plotted
groups = [['item1','item2'], ['item3']]    #defines item groupings

colors = [''] * len(items)
color_space = iter(cm.Paired(np.linspace(0, 1, len(groups))))
for c in groups:
    col = next(color_space)
    for l in c:
        i = items.index(l)
        colors[i] = col

for i, (val, c) in enumerate(zip(vals, colors)):
    plt.bar([i], [val], width=1, color=c)

labels = ['Group 1', 'Group 2']
plt.legend(labels, loc='best')

plt.show()
```

This is the output, but I'd like group 2 to show the next color.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Group the `vals` (y values), `indices` (x values) as you did to `groups`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import numpy as np

indices = [[1, 3], [2], [4]]               # <-----
vals = [[1, 2.5], [1.5], [3.5]]            # <-----
labels = ['Group 1', 'Group 2', 'Group 3']

color_space = iter(cm.Paired(np.linspace(0, 1, len(vals))))
for xs, ys, label in zip(indices, vals, labels):
    col = next(color_space)
    plt.bar(xs, ys, width=1, color=col, label=label)

plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response!
This is definitely a step in the right direction. One issue still remains which is that since I have groups of bars of the same color, the legend incorrectly displays the colors of the first x bars, where x is the number of color groups.

Comment: @sebo, I don't understand your comment. Could you update the question with [minimal, complete example code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows your problem?

Comment: I added an image that describes the problem. If it would still help, I can try to come up with a minimal code example.

Comment: @sebo, Please show the code that produces the image.

Comment: Thanks for the update - that solves the sample code I provided but there's one more constraint in my actual code. The bars have to be ordered the same way as they are in the items and vals lists. On the other hand, the items in groups may be in any order.
So for example, if the groups were [1,3] and [2] in the sample code this wouldn't work.

Comment: @sebo, Do you mean [this (1)](http://imgur.com/wBf9ort)? / or [this (2)](http://imgur.com/gfjrvNw) ?

Comment: In that example I'd still want the order to be [1,2,3], but 1 and 3 would be blue and 2 would be brown.

Comment: @sebo, I updated previous comment to include another image. Check it out.

Comment: The coloring would be like (2), but the values of 2 and 3 would be switched.

Comment: Yes, but the issue there is that if there was a 3rd group with item4, then the legend would display Group 3 as the color of item3.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48333/discussion-between-falsetru-and-sebo)